# How to call a function of the 1st Page from the 3rd Page in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I basically need to call a function from another page. This is my navigation structure: 1st Screen > 2nd Screen > 3rd Screen.

I have read many topics about my problem already but I can't get the perfect answer yet. I have tried using `ScopedModel` and `InheritedWidgets` but it requires a Widget on the tree just to pass data.

I am using the Navigator's named routes with `pushNamed()` function to push these pages.

Let's say my 1st screen has a listview and a function to refresh it: `void refresh()`. How can I call the `refresh()` function directly from the 3rd Screen?

Comment: Why you need to refresh the first page from the third page ?! the correct way is to return your results from the third page when you pop to the first page and using it to render your first page.

Comment: @SaedNabil the real page structure is Home > Settings > Add Account.. After adding an account, Home should automatically refresh it's list view.. Can the 1st screen get the result from the 3rd screen even if there's a 2nd screen in between?

Comment: Now I see, What you are describing is a typical use case for the Bloc pattern I know that it seams complicated but actually this is the common way if you want to manage your state because I assume that you will need it anyway when your app has more state to manage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this multiple ways**
Some of the common ways are

1. Pass the function down through constructors and call it
2. Use rxDart
3. Use scoped_model or any state management library

Comment: Hi epizon, I've already tried scoped_model but I can't see a way to call a function by not using a scopedmodeldescendant which requires to be added in the widget tree. I have multiple parts in 3rd screen that needs to call the 1st screen function. Do I literally have to have multiple scopedmodeldescendant to do this?

Comment: Also how can I pass it to the constructor of the 1sr screen from the 3rd screen without popping the 3rd screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the perfect solution already. I have to use the scoped_model package, create a model to be used as the data source for my ListView and it should be automatically updated anywhere in my app if I try to change the values of my model. And a static way of doing it without using a ScopedModelDescendant Widget is by calling this `ScopedModel.of<MyModel>(context, rebuildOnChange: true).refresh();`

**model.dart file**

```
class DataModel extends Model {
  bool _loading = false;

  String _data = "";

  bool get loading => _loading;
  String get data => _data;

  void refresh() {
    this._loading = true;
    print("loading...");
    notifyListeners();

    String url = "https://reqres.in/api/users/2?delay=1";
    http.get(url).then((response) {
      _loading = false;
      print("refreshed data: ${response.body}");
      this._data = response.body;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  static DataModel of(BuildContext context) =>
      ScopedModel.of<DataModel>(context);
}
```

**main.dart file**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp(model: DataModel()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final DataModel model;
  const MyApp({Key key, @required this.model}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<DataModel>(
      model: model,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'ScopedModel Demo',
        routes: {
          '/': (_) => MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
          '/settings': (_) => SettingsPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart file**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
    void initState() {
      // I can fetch new data here statically without the use of the ScopedModelDescendant in the widget tree.
      DataModel.of(context).refresh();
      super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ScopedModelDescendant<DataModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(model.loading ? "LOADING..." : ""),
                Text("data: ${model.data}"),
                // Statically reading the value from the model
                RaisedButton(child: Text("Read value statically"), onPressed: () {
                  String value = DataModel.of(context).data;
                  print("$value");
                },),
                RaisedButton(child: Text("Settings"), onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/settings");
                },)
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ScopedModelDescendant<DataModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              // here is the ScopedModelDescendant version of refreshing data
              model.refresh();
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```